# What font is used in Code Runner 3 by Nikolai Krill?

Tags: font-identification

[image]It is not Menlo, it is not Consolas, it is not Hack, it isn't anything I could find on web. Please help me find this font (To be specific, the one used in the middle of the picture (the code area: from 'def permute' to 'print [permute....')

I need this exact font because I'm most comfortable with it. Since it's MacOS and I'm running Windows, I need to find the font in order to download it. Thanks in advance!

I tried Font Squirell, What The Font.

Comment: Have you considered just asking him on twitter? Probably easier than guessing. https://twitter.com/nikolaikrill

Comment: The zip of the software CodeRunner can be downloaded on the website. But I couldn't find any files related to fonts in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I donwloaded a trial and at the preferences it says it's Menlo

[image]

[image: Menlo]

[image: menlo character set]

Comment: Can you also show a screenshot of all the characters (like %, *, ...) took in Code Runner trial? Thank you!

Comment: ––––– Done –––––

Comment: My original guess was dejavu sans mono, but it has a different 0

Comment: There's also a very similar font called [Grafista](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/scannerlicker/grafista/regular/)